# convert dictionaries with dictionary into list with same key value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary and within that dictionary contains many dictionaries

for example

```
Dict_a = {'Dict1': {'name': 'Ali', 'age': 19},

        'Dict2': {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 21},

        'Dict2': {'name': 'Ali', 'age': 21}}
```

now I want to convert these dictionary into this dictionaries with common key values go into one list

```
Dict_b = {"distinct": [], "match": [[{'name': 'Ali', 'age': 19},

        {'name': 'Ali', 'age': 21}],

        [{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 21}]] }
```

is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: `Dict_a` is not possible. You cannot have two identical keys.

Comment: If you look carefully both there are 3 dictionaries in dict_a. And I have executed this dict_a in python and its working

Comment: You should split the problem into smaller tasks, then ask us how to perform the ones you don't know how to. Compare the keys of two dictionaries to check if they're the same? Use `dict_1.keys() == dict_2.keys()`. Create a list of all dictionaries with the same keys? `[x for x in Dict_a if x.keys() == DESIRED_KEYS]`. Perform that action for each entry with no repeats? Create the big dict first and just use a `for` loop, not enough space here to write.

Comment: Wrong. Your `Dict_a` has only two items. The third item was overwritten because it has a duplicate key.

Comment: @DYZ I think it can be reasonably inferred that the keys are arbitrary and that the third should read `Dict3`. Is this correct, nupur?

Comment: @Brian I have no idea. The OP should clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
payload = {}

for dict_name, value in Dict_a.items():
    if value["name"] in payload.keys():
        payload[value["name"]].append(value)
    else:
        payload[value["name"]] = [value]

Dict_b = {"distinct": [], "match": payload.values()}
```